# How to uglify VueJS code if not using vue-cli or build tools?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, flask, single-page-application

I am using VueJS in a Python Flask app, where once a page is rendered, VueJS app takes control of the page, and some single page behavior is taken care of.

However, entire VueJS code with all `data`, `methods`, `computed`, etc is visible in source code.

Is there a way to uglify this?

Note: I'm not using vue-cli or using any proper javascript build process.

Comment: May I ask how you serve the app when you don't build it?

Comment: the url `app.com/my_page` gets loaded from server controlled by Flask's Jinja2 templating, and then vue app is initialized in this after page load.

Comment: Okay, and how do you bundle the vue files? Are you just using the Vue cdn and then ha plain JS in which you define your vue components? if so perhaps something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js would be an option?

Comment: yes, vue from CDN, and then plain Vue app (data, components) in plain JS.

Comment: Then I would recommend installing the lib I shared globally and watch your js file with nodemon. and execute the uglify on change.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.